# This COM object can not automate the makepy process - please run makepy manually for this object

Tags: python, com, pywin32, win32com, office-automation

I have been using this script for automating some tasks that include copy and pasting raw data from CSV files into an excel template, its been working for months but today ive gotten this error.

Exception has occurred: TypeError
This COM object can not automate the makepy process - please run makepy manually for this object

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
File "C:\Users\alfredop\Pack EOL.py", line 65, in 
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
So far i ve tried the following with no luck:
Uninstall/Reinstall pywin32
deleting the genpy folder
restarting the computer

But nothing seems to work. One thing i did notice is that the makepy.py executable is not present anywhere in my pywin32 folder as well, not sure if that has anything to do with it. Any suggestions?  Heres the script and i get the error in line 65(excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application"))

``    # Convert the CSV data to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame([row[:148] for row in final_rows], columns=rows[0][:148])

```
# Copy the DataFrame to the clipboard
pyperclip.copy(df.to_csv(index=False, sep="\t", header=False))

# Open Excel and paste the data into the "DUs_DCH Data" sheet of the "BigHorn DCIR Template" workbook
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(root_dir2, "9MC3DV2-XXX Bighorn DCIR Template.xlsx"))
workbook.SaveAs(os.path.join(root_dir, f"1. 9MC3DV2-{root_dir3} EOL {root_dir4} RUN {root_dir5} C3 MANAFLEX DCIR.xlsx"))
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("DUs_DCH Data")
worksheet.Range("B2").PasteSpecial()
workbook.Save()
workbook.Close()
excel.Quit()``
```

Comment: Try using `win32com.client.Dispatch` instead. For example, see https://github.com/Hridai/Automating_Outlook .

Comment: I'm on Python 3.9, and `makepy.py` is in the `...\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client` folder under the Python installation. Suggest you persevere with `EnsureDispatch()` as (i) it enforces case sensitivity on method/param names (which will avoid grief down the line), and (ii) allows you to access the Enum parameter names via the `win32com.clients.constants` dictionary, rather than relying on hard-coded numbers.